Is there a way to build and inject a file inside a webpack loader?
Is there a way to build and inject a file inside a webpack loader? I want to make an HTML loader which replaces a string with a url of an emitted file i build inside the loader.
module.exports = function (source) {
  // source = html file content

  const tsFilename = 'foo.ts'
  // I want to load and build `foo.ts` file, rules for this have been configured in webpack
  const tsSource = 'source parsed file'
  this.emitFile('output.js', tsSource)

  source.replace('__JS_FILE__', 'output.js')

  return source
}

Using loadModule only returns the source code but will not compile the file. I thought about using something like a childCompiler, but no idea how this should work.

Write your own loader and chain them? (because that's one of the critical parts of loaders: you can just chain however many you need, where each one does only the one thing it's good at).
